# Getting method name from an Action delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, methodinfo

I'm trying to get the method name passed into an Action delegate. This is what I have:

```
private static void DoAction(params Action<Group>[] actions)
{
    foreach (Action<Group> action in actions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(action.Method.Name);
    }
}
```

And in main, this is how it gets called:

```
DoAction(y => y.DoBar(), z => z.DoFoo());
```

After the execution of DoAction() method I was hoping to see "DoFoo" and "DoBar" on the screen, but it instead I see <`Main>b__0` and `<Main>b__1`. I was just wondering if there's a way to get the actual name of the target method from an action delegate? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the input type to an `Expression` and then see if the expression is a method call:

```
private static void DoAction(params Expression<Action<Group>>[] actions)
{
    foreach (var exp in actions)
    {
        var method = exp.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if(method != null)
            Console.WriteLine(method.Method.Name);

        // similar method for properties
        var member = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (member != null)
            Console.WriteLine(member.Member);

        // execute the Action
        Action<Group> act = exp.Compile();

        Group g = new Group();  // create a Group to act on
        act(g);  // perform the action

    }

}
```

Comment: How can I invoke the method now? action() doesn't work. Expression.Invoke() also requires arguments for the method. Assuming Foo() and Bar() methods both take arguments, how can specify the arguments in main and invoke it in DoAction()?

Comment: @programmer93 use `Expression.Compile()` to convert it to an `Action`.  See my updated answer.